# Firebase addValueEventListener excute later in loop

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase addValueEventListener to fetch the data from firebase database, below is my code.

```
    DatabaseReference chatMessagesDb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("ChatRooms");
DatabaseReference usersDb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");

chatMessagesDb.child(chatRoomId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    for (DataSnapshot messages : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        Message message = messages.getValue(Message.class); // Message is a data Model for chatMessages.
        userDb.child(message.getCreatorId()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


           }

           @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
        }

}

@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

}
});
```

I am applying `addValueEventListener` on chatMessagesDb and providing a key chatRoomId, so it will fetch all the messages from database of the chatRoom with id equals to chatRoomId. Now, for each message I want to fetch the creator of the Message, so I am adding a `addValueEventListener` on users database to fetch the details of the creator of a Message.

It should work like, for 1st loop of Message it should call the `addValueEventListener` on users db for the creator of that message, but it doesn't work like this. First, it loop through all the messages, then it starts calling `addValueEventListener` on users db.

How can I solve it? Please let me know if anyone have idea about this, this would be a great help.

Thanks a lot in advanced.

Comment: When you get the user data, use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent()` instead

Comment: But I need to show the changes if the name of the user get changed, that's why I use addValueEventListner and it will give the same issue with addListenerForSingleValueEvent as well.

Comment: Oh, I just got what your meaning is. So you want to show message1, user1, message2, user2 ... in that order? Your code actually has done that. But because the result when you request user1 data, the not acquired immediately, you may think there is some error on the flow. Is it really need to be message>user>message>user flow? Can you explain why you need that? Maybe we can help you with another way to accomplish it

Comment: After fetching the creator name of each message, I want to add this data in a list and show in Recyclerview. Now with the above code before getting the user name of creators, it loop through the messages and It is difficult to identify the user name of particular message, how can I solve this, please help if you have any idea.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's little late to answer, but I think other guys who are learning can be helpful. In case of message from db, use `ChildValueEventListener`. It returns 4 methods to implement, so any change in the db of a particular node will be listened and return that value.

Comment: This answer might be more helpful if you format it and fix typos and grammar. Please be more explicit. For example "4 methods to...", please elaborate on that.